# Pivot data in Azure Stream Analytics using Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, azure-stream-analytics

I have a data like below with dynamic parameters ;

```
    [
    {"deviceid":"d1","parameter"="p1" value="1" timestamp="2018-03-22T12:33:00"},
    {"deviceid":"d1","parameter"="p2" value="2" timestamp="2018-03-22T12:34:00"},
    {"deviceid":"d1","parameter"="p2" value="3" timestamp="2018-03-22T12:35:00"},
    {"deviceid":"d2","parameter"="p1" value="4" timestamp="2018-03-22T12:36:00"},
    {"deviceid":"d2","parameter"="p2" value="5" timestamp="2018-03-22T12:37:00"},
    {"deviceid":"d2","parameter"="p2" value="6" timestamp="2018-03-22T12:38:00"},
    {"deviceid":"d2","parameter"="p1" value="7" timestamp="2018-03-22T12:43:00"},
    {"deviceid":"d2","parameter"="p1" value="8" timestamp="2018-03-22T12:44:00"},
    {"deviceid":"d2","parameter"="p2" value="9" timestamp="2018-03-22T12:45:00"},
    {"deviceid":"d1","parameter"="p1" value="10" timestamp="2018-03-22T12:46:00"},
    {"deviceid":"d1","parameter"="p1" value="11" timestamp="2018-03-22T12:47:00"},
    {"deviceid":"d1","parameter"="p2" value="12" timestamp="2018-03-22T12:49:00"}
    ]
```

I want to pivot that parameter values(for every 10 minutes window) and display last received value of each parameter for each device(Parameters will be dynamic not just p1 and p2); So essentially created Columns from Parameters values pivot all other data aggregates by windowtime.

---

### | deviceid|     windowtime       |     p1    |     p2      |......n

### | d1      | 2018-03-22 12:40     |     1     |      3      |

### | d2      | 2018-03-22 12:40     |     4     |      6      |

### | d2      | 2018-03-22 12:50     |     8     |      9      |

### | d1      | 2018-03-22 12:50     |     11    |     12      |

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the data array into seperate objects, each representing a period and then log those.
The short way to get the period is to just slice away everything not needed from the date field and add a 0.

That would give intervals of x:30:00.000 until x:39:59.999, so excluding x:40:00.000
You could parse the date into an actual date object if you need more fine grained control of which item belongs in which period, like you show with rounding up the time to the nearest 10min in the future.

So after fixing the invalid format of the source data, I end up with this:

```js
const data = [
  {"deviceid":"d1", "parameter":"p1", "value":"1", "timestamp":"2018-03-22T12:33:00"},
  {"deviceid":"d1", "parameter":"p2", "value":"2", "timestamp":"2018-03-22T12:34:00"},
  {"deviceid":"d1", "parameter":"p2", "value":"3", "timestamp":"2018-03-22T12:35:00"},
  {"deviceid":"d2", "parameter":"p1", "value":"4", "timestamp":"2018-03-22T12:36:00"},
  {"deviceid":"d2", "parameter":"p2", "value":"5", "timestamp":"2018-03-22T12:37:00"},
  {"deviceid":"d2", "parameter":"p2", "value":"6", "timestamp":"2018-03-22T12:38:00"},
  {"deviceid":"d2", "parameter":"p1", "value":"7", "timestamp":"2018-03-22T12:43:00"},
  {"deviceid":"d2", "parameter":"p1", "value":"8", "timestamp":"2018-03-22T12:44:00"},
  {"deviceid":"d2", "parameter":"p2", "value":"9", "timestamp":"2018-03-22T12:45:00"},
  {"deviceid":"d1", "parameter":"p1","value":"10", "timestamp":"2018-03-22T12:46:00"},
  {"deviceid":"d1", "parameter":"p1", "value":"11", "timestamp":"2018-03-22T12:47:00"},
  {"deviceid":"d1", "parameter":"p2", "value":"12", "timestamp":"2018-03-22T12:49:00"}
];

const hash_intervals = data.reduce(( intervals, item ) => {
  const interval = `|${ item.deviceid }|${ item.timestamp.slice( 0, 15 ) }0|`;
  if ( !intervals[ interval ] ) intervals[ interval ] = {};
  intervals[ interval ][ item.parameter ] = item.value;
  return intervals;
}, {});

Object
  .entries( hash_intervals )
  .forEach(([ interval, items ]) => console.log( `${ interval }${ Object.values( items ).join( '|' ) }` ));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Essentially i want to tabularize the data thats being reported, with Parameters values as column names. does that help clarify ?

Comment: I changed the code so it would only show the last received value per parameter. The explanation just is a tiny different then. Reduce into an object for each interval instead of reduce into an array, so you can overwrite previous values.